# Finding a dynamically added control on an aspx page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-2.0, code-behind

I have an asp page "A" and I've created a user control "B"

When I do A.Controls.Add(B), I would like to make an element, say a TableRow which is defined inside control "B", invisible via code behind.

When looking through Controls of "A", I cannot seem to find that table row.

Any hints?

I'm sure it is something really simple I'm missing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should expose the controls that are modifiable and accessible from outside as properties.
 [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdbz1a66%28VS.80%29.aspx)

But consider not to expose the whole control itself but only f.e. a Text-Property of a Textbox, because that prevents from unintentional and unpredictable behaviour.
A usercontrol should encapsulate complexity and should be (mostly) reusable. The more control you offer to the controls(f.e. the page) that use the usercontrol, the less reusable and the more error-phrone they are.

If you for example have built a Login-Control with a Textbox for the Username and a Textbox for the Password, it makes sense to offer properties named Username and Password instead of returning the Textboxes itself. The properties each return the respective  Textbox-Text value.

In your example with the TableRow, what is its purpose? You should expose a property with a meaningful name to control its visibility(f.e. `ShowTitle` if the row contains a title, the getter/setter would return/set the actual tablerow's visible state).

Of course you need a reference to your UserControl if you want to access its properties. You should provide sourcecode if you have problems on finding it on the page. It depends on where you have created and added it. Normally you will find controls with [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) on the [NamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) (f.e. the NamingContainer of a control defined in a GridView's TemplateColumn is the GridViewRow itself).

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `FindControl` method from Page to find a specific control by its Id,
I'm not sure if you want to find that UserControl 'A' you've added or a control inside it, you should be able to use the same method to find the control inside as long as you know the Id and if this table row was declared through the xml, it has the runat="server" attribute set.

hope it helps!

Comment: FindControl is not recursive. You would have to know exactly which container it was added to. In a dynamically added environment, it's possible that the control he's looking for is not one he knows the name of at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use a recursive extension method - works nicely regardless of nesting etc. You can hack it to return a control with a particular ID.

Param *Parent* can be any control, including a Webform or a UserControl   :-)

```
    //Recursively get all the Controls within parent
    public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(this Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
        {
            yield return control;
            foreach (Control descendant in control.GetAllControls())
            {
                yield return descendant;
            }
        }
    }
```